# Find the vertical asymptote(s)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I re-post this problem because the answer I received here is the same as mine, and is different from the answer sheet. My answer to this problem is that the vertical asymptotes are at $x=0$ and $x=1$. The answer sheet says $x=1$ only. I don't know who is right, and why $x=0$ is not a vertical asymptote.

> Find the vertical asymptote(s) for the graph of 
>   $$y=\log_2x+\log_2(x-1).$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is not defined for $x\le 1$. Hence $x=0\ $ cannot be an asymptote.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Look at the domain of your function. We need $x-1 >0$ and $x>0$.